# Как массово удалить известные ссылки в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть около тысячи ссылок, которые необходимо удалить из WordPress, не затрагивая текст ссылки. Есть такой код, который подсказали на другом ресурсе, но он совершенно не работает. Вставляется в functions.php для единичного прогона.

```
function links_remove () {
    $args = array ('numberposts' => 9999);
    $allposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $allposts as $post ) {
        $id = $post->ID;
        $content = $post->post_content;
        $links_mass=array(
            /*
            Здесь список абсолютно разных ссылок через запятую
            */
            );
        foreach($links_mass as $link) {
            $pattern = '/<a([^>]*)href="' . preg_quote($link, '/') . '([^"]*)"([^>]*)>|<\/a>/i';
            $new_content = preg_replace ($pattern, "", $content);
        }   
        $new_post = array();
        $new_post['ID'] = $id;
        $new_post['post_content'] = $new_content;
        wp_update_post( $new_post );        
    }
} 
add_action ('init', 'links_remove');
```

Answer (score 1):

Почти помогло вот так

```
function links_remove () {
$args = array ('numberposts' => 9999);
    $allposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $allposts as $post ) {
        $id = $post->ID;
        $content = $post->post_content;
        $links_mass=array(
        'site.com'
        );

        foreach($links_mass as $link) {
        $_ = str_replace($links_mass, '', $content);
        $new_content =  preg_replace('~<a\s*href="">([^<]+)<\/a>~', "$1", $_);
        $new_post = array();
        $new_post['ID'] = $id;
        $new_post['post_content'] = $new_content;
        wp_update_post( $new_post );       
       }   
   } 
}
add_action ('init', 'links_remove');
```

но ссылки становятся вот такие

```html
<a href="http://">Сайт</a>
```

Как бы и от них избавиться?

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей надежнее разбирать структуру html внутри контента. Для этого есть простой и удобный инструмент - [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm). Он реализован в виде одного файла `simple_html_dom.php`, который надо скачать по [ссылке](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simple_html_dom.php/download) и поместить в основную папку темы, где находится `functions.php`.

В `functions`.php следует добавить ваш код, который я несколько модифицировал:

```
function links_remove () {
    // Подключаем DOM parser
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Лучше объявить массив один раз, вне циклов
    $links_mass = array(
        'site.com'
    );

    $args = array ('numberposts' => -1);        // -1 означает все записи
    $allposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $allposts as $post ) {
        $id = $post->ID;
        $content = $post->post_content;
        $html = str_get_html($content); // получаем структуру DOM контента
        // Находим все ссылки в контенте
        foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
            // сравниваем со ссылками в массиве
            foreach($links_mass as $link) {
                if (strpos($element->href, $link) !== false) {
                    // есть такая ссылка, убираем в элементе все, кроме текста ссылки
                    $element->outertext = $element->innertext;
                }
            }
        }
        $post->post_content = (string) $html->save();   // модифицируем контент
        wp_update_post( $post );    // обновляем пост
   } 
}
add_action ('init', 'links_remove');
```

Код рабочий, проверил.

Answer (score -1):

Для вашей цели стоит использовать `SQL`-запрос. Пример замены старой ссылки на новую:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 
‘<a href="http://">Сайт</a>’, ‘Сайт’)
```

Comment: Этот способ не годится для замены множества ссылок, перечисленных в массиве `$links_mass=array(...);`. Кроме того, ссылки могут содержать `<a class="foo"...>` и т.п.