# Как удалить кучу известных ссылок в wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Есть около тысячи ссылок, которые необходимо удалить из wordpress не затрагивая текст ссылки. Есть такой код, который подсказали на другом ресурсе, но он работает неверно. Вставляется в functions.php для единичного прогона.

```
function links_remove () {
$args = array ('numberposts' => 9999);
$allposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $allposts as $post ) {
    $id = $post->ID;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $links_mass=array(
    /*
 Здесь сотни абсолютно разных ссылок через запятую
    */
    'site.com'
    );

    foreach($links_mass as $link) {
    $_ = str_replace($links_mass, '', $content);
    $new_content =  preg_replace('~<a\s*href="">([^<]+)<\/a>~', "$1", $_);
    $new_post = array();
    $new_post['ID'] = $id;
    $new_post['post_content'] = $new_content;
    wp_update_post( $new_post );       
   }   
 } 
}
 add_action ('init', 'links_remove');
```

Он находит и "удаляет" ссылки только на той страничке которую я загружаю в данный момент. Т.е. если это главная, то там он ничего не удалит или если пост, который не имеет ссылок из массива, то тоже ничего не изменится. А если это пост в котором есть ссылки из массива, то ссылка становится вида :

```
<a href="http://">Сайт</a>
```

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588276/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-wordpress

Comment: вы создаёте уже третий вопрос на эту тему, остановитесь

Comment: Потому что на него пытаются ответить только в первые пару часов.

Answer (score 0):

Я подобную задачу решал "топором" - экспортировал таблицу posts, в notepad++ автозаменой по регулярному выражению затирал ссылки.
Однако, у меня не было никаких "легальных" исходящих, я не вешал ссылки на изображения, поэтому задача была довольно простая - требовалось просто затереть все теги от "" и "".