# Вывод изображения с записи WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Самописная тема WP, вывожу на странице запись, но не могу вывести изображения, не thumbnails, а изображения, которые я загружаю в записи.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю в сторону `wp_get_attachment_url()`, но не хватает опыта, не выходит, решение найти тоже не могу

```
<?
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $product = get_post($id, OBJECT);
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id);
    echo $product->post_title; 
    echo get_post_meta($id,'price',true);
    echo wp_get_attachment_url($id);
?>
```

Лишний код убрал

Comment: Вывести надо большую фото в редакторе или ту, что справа, где миниатюра?

Comment: фото в редакторе, их там >1

Comment: В ставка в пост происходит через кнопку "Добавить Медиафайл". Из вопроса непонятно, с выводом каких изображений проблема?

Comment: Добавил я медиафайл, вывести его не могу на странице

Comment: Что касается вывода изображений, который в редакторе (с текстом), то эти изображения выводятся в шаблоне вместе со всем контентом через `<?php the_content(); ?>`, а про миниатюру можно почитать тут: http://wp-kama.ru/function/the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изображения находятся в содержимом поста. Получить его можно так:

```
$content = $product->post_content;
```

Дальше нужно обработать этот html контент, вычленив из него теги . Это и есть изображения. Сделать это можно либо строковыми функциями, либо применив вот такой код:

```
get_images($content);

function get_images ($content) {
    // Подключаем DOM parser
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = str_get_html($content); // получаем структуру DOM контента
    // Находим все изображения в контенте
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        echo $element->outertext;   // выводим изображения в виде html кода <img src="...">
    }
}
```

Да, пояснения к этому коду можно найти в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588276/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-wordpress/600162#600162).